# Objective C + out of scope error

Tags: objective-c

I am declaring a static NSString in .h file as:

`static NSString *bowlerName;`

`@interface PlayMatchController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {`
`......`
`}`

`@end`

In the .m file I am assigning that NSString variable with some value:

`bowlerName = @"ABC";`

Later in the .m file when I try to access that variable using the debugger when I put the mouse on that variable, I get the message like "Out of Scope" and than I continue to debug the program, at the end it will crash and give error like "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the declaration within the implementation file, rather than the header

[Static string variable in Objective C on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980083/static-string-variable-in-objective-c-on-iphone)