# How to do class constants in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to use something like

```
if (carRecord.status == CarRecord.statusRepaired) {  // using a class constant
    // ...
}
```

such as in a car repair shop, the `carRecord` object's state `status` is checked against the `CarRecord` class's constant.  In Objective-C, is there such a way?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/980272/169277 or this one http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/java-developers-guide-to-static-variables-in-objective-c.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how would you define it in .h file :

```
typedef enum CarRecordStatus {
    CarRecordStatusBroken = 0,
    CarRecordStatusRepaired,
} CarRecordStatus;

@interface MyClassName : NSObject    
..interfacebody..
@end
```

Use it inside MyClassName or any other just import it that's it.

Answer (score 7):

You would typically do this with an `enum`. For example:

```
//=== CarRecord.h:
typedef enum CarRecordStatus {
    CarRecordStatusBroken = 0,
    CarRecordStatusRepaired
} CarRecordStatus;

@interface CarRecord (NSObject) {
    CarRecordStatus _status;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CarRecordStatus status;

@end

//=== CarRecord.m:
@implementation CarRecord

@synthesize status=_status;

- (void)someMethod {
    if (self.status == CarRecordStatusRepaired) {
         //...
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I think he's not looking for enum, I think he means static variable .. maybe I'm wrong

Comment: so this will be defined only within the class?  Or are they global constants?

Comment: They are defined only within the class, and all those that import it's header.

Comment: The `enum` could be used anywhere you import the header in which it's defined. I'm not saying it's exactly equivalent to your code, just that it's the conventional way of approaching this problem in Objective-C.

Comment: Can you put the complete code... Is it all inside the .h and how to use it inside and outside of the class?  thx

Comment: thanks... will you use a small `k` in front for constants?  I saw some code that uses a small `k` and looks like a convention for constants

Comment: So the user of this class cannot use `CarRecord.CarRecordStatusBroken` but just have to use a single name `CarRecordStatusBroken` huh?  (not part of the class)