# Access static class variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I would like to use class variables outside of the class.

By 'outside', I mean the main function where I instantiate the class.

```c
@interface Class: NSObject
static int var_class;   // Class variable
{
    int var_object; // Object variable
}
@end

@implementation Class
@end
```

In order to access `var_object`, the object variable, we use:

```c
int main(void)
{
    Class *object = [Class new];

    // Access to the variable
    object->var_object;
    (*object).var_object;

    return 0;
}
```

I thought I could access `var_class`, the class variable, in the same way.

But none of them worked. (Unable to compile)

```c
Class.var_class;
// -> Generates error: could not find setter/getter for 'count' in class 'TheClass'

Class->var_class;
// -> Generates error: error: expected '.' before '->' token
```

How can I get/set the class variable's value?

Declaring a function is the way to access class variables, but I want it simpler.

```c
@interface Class: NSObject
static int var_class;   // Class variable
+(int) get;
+(void) set: (int) val;
@end

@implementation Class
+(int) get
{
    return var_class;
}
+(int) set: (int) val
{
    var_class = val;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no static class variables in Objective-C, thus you can't expect something like `Class.var_class`. This is why your last proposition is a correct one, and commonly adopted. See, [Does Objective-C support class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187530/does-objective-c-support-class-variables).

----EDIT----

Some new constructions were added to Objective-C, see [Objective-C Class Properties](https://armadsen.micro.blog/2016/06/14/objectivec-class-properties.html). Thus syntax is admitted, while there is no automatic synthesis.

Comment: Actually `Class.var_class` syntax is possible with `@property(class, ...) ` and technically even without it, but not to access the variable itself only the class property.

Comment: @Kamil.S Excellent, I was not aware that Objective-C evolved even after Swift tried to replace it! Thanks.

Comment: So I have to create a function or use a property instead. Thank you both!